# php decode special entities in mysql

Tags: php, pdo, decode, html-entities

I am very new to PDO and I am trying to decode all the rows in my table "test" which contains special entities for instance "('L& eacute;on: The Professional')" instead of "Léon:The Professional".

So, here is what I tried:

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from test");
$stmt->execute();
while ($results = $stmt->fetch()){

 $b = html_entity_decode($stmt);
 echo $b;
 }
```

but I have no output printed..

Could someone kindly help me fix it?

Comment: As you can see, `$query` is not defined yet. So it has no 'execute' function. Perhaps you should try to call it on `$conn` or `$stmt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `prepare()` returns a statement object (`$stmt` in your case)
- `fetch()` returns associative array where the index would be the column name

---

```
$sql = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 from test";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = array()
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
   $resutlt[] = array('column1' => html_entity_decode($row['column1']),
                      'column2' => html_entity_decode($row['column2']),
                      'column3' => html_entity_decode($row['column3'])
                );
}
var_dump($result);
return $result;
```

---

EDIT: to replace the values

```
//prepare select
$sql = "SELECT id, column1, column2, column3 from test";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

//prepare update
$update_sql = "UPDATE test SET column1=?,column2=?,column3=? WHERE id = ?;";
$update_stmt = $conn->prepare($update_sql);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
//update
$update_stmt->execute(array(html_entity_decode($row['column1']),
                            html_entity_decode($row['column2']),
                            html_entity_decode($row['column3']),
                            $row['id']
                );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete explanation. so, $results returns an array containing the columns that I specify in fetch? Should I write while ($results = $stmt->fetch(columnName)) ??  sorry, if my questions are really beginner :(

Comment: Thank a lot! it works just perfectly, just one more question: if I want to update all the rows in my db with the decoded one, Is it OK if I put var_dump($result) line inside the while loop, and then insert the dump data into a new table or it is better to update table with $result[columnName]?

Comment: Im not sure what do you mean? do you want to replace the values with the encoded ones ? var_dump is just to dump data for debugging

Comment: yes I meant if I want to update (replace) the values with encoded one, could I get output in csv dump or is it better to update table with new values?

Comment: @mOna I expended on my answer, but please make sure you test it, I just quickly typed it in notepad so make sure it works

Comment: Thanks again for your time and kind support. It is partially solved but I don't know why the words containing non-english characters like "Léon: The Professional" is now presented as "L?on: The Professional", also WALL·E is shown as WALL?E!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62535/discussion-between-meda-and-mona).

Comment: finally worked :) I set utf8mb4 in my table columns and also in my php script for connection, then I used yr code (the original one with html_entity_decode and it corrected everything!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You did not define `$query`, thus it has no `execute()` function. If you wish to execute your prepared statement, you should call `$stmt->execute()`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are right so I edited my question, but still I have no output printed..  (although the previous error was solved)